# Are there downsides of using & inside Bash scripts?

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, mariadb

I am making a script that should install MariaDB/MySQL server and then create users and such. For this I need `mysqld_safe` to be running, which doesn't have a daemon mode, so the script won't continue. Doing `mysqld_safe &` works it seams.

```
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe > /dev/null 2>&1 &

RET=1
while [[ RET -ne 0 ]]; do
    sleep 5
    mysql -uroot -e "status" > /dev/null 2>&1
    RET=$?
done

...
```

**Question**

Are there downsides, or is it bad practice, to use `&` inside bash scripts?

If, what is the recommended method?

Comment: What does your `mysql -uroot -e "status"` command do for you?

Comment: It will only return success if the database is running, so this way the script will only continue, when mysql/mariadb is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you have any alternative to `&` if you need to run several processes in parallel, and it looks like you really do.

Running several parallel processes without good reason exposes you to all kinds of race conditions and therefore should be avoided, hence the general advice not to use `&` thoughtlessly in your scripts.

I just hope you didn't forget to terminate the `mysqld_safe` process at the end of your script.

Answer (score 0):

You want a negative answer, but I do this also to improve a stability of my script in raspberry.

I also store PID of the process so that I could kill it later in the script.

I use lockfile, and I check the existence of the 'mysql_safe' before running it.

However, I cannot comment on if it is a good practice.

Comment: Sounds interesting. I do `mysqladmin -uroot shutdown` instead of the PID trick.